# Retrofit list field inside JSON not working

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, retrofit2

I'm using the lastest version of retrofit (2.9.0) to receive data from an API, the data structure (They have the getters and setters):

**FamilyResponse.Java**

```
@SerializedName("codigo")
@Expose
private String codigo;

@SerializedName("estado")
@Expose
private String estado;

@Expose
@SerializedName("List")
private List<Family> list;
```

**Family.java**

```
@SerializedName("idFampr")
@Expose
private String idFamilia;

@SerializedName("nomFam")
@Expose
private String nombre;
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
       Call<FamilyResponse> call = ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().getFamiliaProductos(new FamilyRequest("1"));

    call.enqueue(new Callback<FamilyResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FamilyResponse> call, Response<FamilyResponse> response) {
            FamilyResponse familyResponse = response.body();
            if(familyResponse!=null)
            {
                for(Family family:familyResponse.getList()){
                Log.d("Familia",family.getNombre());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FamilyResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

I'm receiving the following:

```
{
"codigo": "1",
"estado": "Consulta satisfactoria",
"list": [
    {
        "idFampr": 1,
        "nomFam": "Category 1",
        "icoFam": "img1.jpg",
        "ordFan": 1
    },
    {
        "idFampr": 2,
        "nomFam": "Category 2",
        "icoFam": "img2.jpg",
        "ordFan": 2
    },
    {
        "idFampr": 3,
        "nomFam": "Category 3",
        "icoFam": "img3.jpg",
        "ordFan": 3
    },
    {
        "idFampr": 4,
        "nomFam": "Category 4",
        "icoFam": "img4.jpg",
        "ordFan": 4
    },
    {
        "idFampr": 5,
        "nomFam": "Category 5",
        "icoFam": "img5.jpg",
        "ordFan": 5
    }
]
```

}

When i try to read the response.body() for the "List" field is null, but estado and codigo have the correct values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your `@SerializedName("List")` to `@SerializedName("list")` in `FamilyResponse.Java` class.

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("list")
private List<Family> list;
```

For more info, please check [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

Comment: Ohh thanks, i cant believe i made an error so dumb. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Change your @SerializedName("List") to @SerializedName("list"), the name value must be the same as your JSON attribute

> NOTE: The value you specify in this annotation must be a valid JSON field name.

[Check documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)